# Caret triangle reversed, shows drop down when list is already displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this very annoying drop down `list` which is showing the wrong triangle:

[image]

As you can see, the arrows are reversed on both images and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/mtpLp1eu/

Comment: Whether the arrows are wrong or not is matter of perception. They look fine if interpreted one way and wrong if interpreted another.

Comment: @Ouroborus not really a carat will usually always point down before the menu is open on the web, its standard even in default html select boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ["border-based triangles"](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#triangle-up), the arrow points "inwards", from the edge it's built on towards its object's center.

To switch your arrows, adjust the CSS:

```
#nav-trigger span:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #e3e3e3; /* changed */
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}
#nav-trigger span.open:after {
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-top: solid 10px #fff; /* changed */
  border-bottom: none; /* changed */
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}
```